# Visual understanding of the GAE datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to understand how the Google App Engine (GAE) datastore is designed and how to use it. I am having a bit of a hard time to visualise the structure from the description at the [getting started page](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore).

Can somebody explain the datastore using figures for us visually oriented people? Or point to a good tutorial again with visual learning in mind?

I am specifically looking for answers with diagrams/figures that explains how GAE is used.

Comment: What, specifically, would you like to visualize?

Comment: @DanielRoseman: Basically how the different terms relate: Entities, Keys, Parent/child relations, ancestors. It is described as a hierarchy in the text, and I would like a visual representation of that. Also how entity groups and ancestor queries related to that.

Comment: offtopic: undskyld at jeg blander mig sådan her, men jeg ved ikke lige hvordan jeg ellers kan skrive til dig :) Jeg så [dit spm heromme](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/5450/what-is-the-miu-unit-as-used-in-hcg-levels) og håber at du ikke føler dig jaget væk! [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/388/parenting) hvis du vil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simplified I've understood that GAE can be viewed as a hashmap of hashmaps.

That said you could view it like this:

[image: GAE datastore visualised]

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the type of answer I was looking for. :)

Answer (score 3):

The 2008 IO session "Under the Covers of the Google App Engine Datastore" has a good visual overview of the datastore.

https://sites.google.com/site/io/under-the-covers-of-the-google-app-engine-datastore

http://snarfed.org/datastore_talk.html

For more IO talks go to:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/videoresources

Answer (score 1):

I guess there's no correct answer here, just different mind models. Depending on your programming background you may find mine enlightning, disturbing or both. I picture the datastore as a single huge distributed key-value collection of buckets that comprises all entity data of any kind in any namespace and all GAE apps of all users. A single bucket is called an entity group. It has a root key which (under the hood) consists of your appID, a namespace, a kind, an entity ID or name. In an entity group resides one ore more entities which have keys extending the root key. The entity belonging to the root key itself may or may not exist. Operations within a single entity group are atomic (transactional). An entity is a simple map-like datastructure. The 2 built-in indexes (ascending and descending) again are 2 giant sorted collections of index entries. Each index entry is a datastructure of appID,namespace,kind,property name,property type,property value,entity key - in that order.
Each (auto-)indexed value of each property of each entity creates 2 such index entries. There's another index with just entity keys in it. Custom indexes however go to yet another sorted collection with entries containing appID,namespace,index type,combined index value, entity key. That's the only part of the whole datastore that uses meta-data. It stores an index definition which tells the store how the combined index value is formed from the entity. This is the picture that's burnt into my mind and from which I know how to make the datastore happy.